# Replace media external links with local links

Tags: urls, media

I use an automatic post importer in WordPress and add the images in post content with the external URL, I want to replace the link with the local site links.

DB function could do the trick.

eg: oldlink.com replace with newlink.com

Note: there is a 5K images in that way and need to be changed.

I have try to use search replace but not work because changing the externalk URL in the post content winch is I want to keep it. So the tick is to replace only the link with  tag

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was fixing image URLs in my posts with the next SQL-query

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content, '<old url>','<new url>'));
```